# Assigning a default value to a property

Tags: c#

I have an xml like so:

```
<Settings>
  <User default="Programmer"></User>
  <Level default="2"></Level>
<Settings>
```

This is deserialized to an object of type UserSettings:

```
[Serializable]
[XmlRoot("Settings")]
public class UserSettings
{
    [XmlElement("User")]
    public string User { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Level")]
    public string Level { get; set; }

}
```

The UserSettings object gives whatever the values are there for the tags at runtime.

I want the class to return the default attribute value when either the tag is empty or the tag is absent in the incoming xml.

So if there is an object objUserSettings of type UserSettings then

`objUserSettings.User`

should give "Programmer", or whatever is in default attribute value in the xml if the tag User is empty.

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding another answer because I had some fun with this question.  Take it or leave it, but this is probably how I would attack this feature.

Here's an answer that is more complicated, but it gives you type safety using generics and most of the heavy lifting is  done in one base class (no need to copy/paste the same code over and over).

Added a property to UserSettings to show an example of another type...

```
[Serializable]
[XmlRoot("Settings")]
public class UserSettings
{
    public UserSettings()
    {
        User = new DefaultableStringValue();
        Level = new DefaultableIntegerValue();
        IsFullscreen = new DefaultableBooleanValue();
    }

    [XmlElement("User")]
    public DefaultableStringValue User { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Level")]
    public DefaultableIntegerValue Level { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("IsFullscreen")]
    public DefaultableBooleanValue IsFullscreen { get; set; }
}
```

Simple implementations of typed DefaultableValues...

```
[Serializable]
public class DefaultableStringValue : DefaultableValue<string>
{
    public DefaultableStringValue() : base(s => s) { }
}

[Serializable]
public class DefaultableIntegerValue : DefaultableValue<int>
{
    public DefaultableIntegerValue() : base(int.Parse) { }
}

[Serializable]
public class DefaultableBooleanValue : DefaultableValue<bool>
{
    public DefaultableBooleanValue() : base(bool.Parse) { }
}
```

Base class that does all of the heavy lifting of parsing and caching parsed values...

```
[Serializable]
public abstract class DefaultableValue<T>
{
    protected Func<string, T> _parsingFunc;

    private string _valueText;
    private T _cachedValue;
    private bool _isValueCached;

    private string _defaultText;
    private T _cachedDefault;
    private bool _isDefaultCached;

    protected DefaultableValue(Func<string, T> parsingFunc)
    {
        _parsingFunc = parsingFunc;
        _isValueCached = false;
        _isDefaultCached = false;
    }

    [XmlAttribute("default")]
    public string DefaultText
    {
        get { return _defaultText; }
        set
        {
            _defaultText = value;
            _isDefaultCached = false;
        }
    }

    [XmlText]
    public string ValueText
    {
        get { return _valueText; }
        set
        {
            _valueText = value;
            _isValueCached = false;
        }
    }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public T Default
    {
        get
        {
            if (_isDefaultCached)
                return _cachedDefault;

            if (HasDefault)
                return ParseAndCacheValue(DefaultText, out _cachedDefault, out _isDefaultCached);

            return default(T);
        }
        set
        {
            DefaultText = value.ToString();
            _cachedDefault = value;
            _isDefaultCached = true;
        }
    }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public T Value
    {
        get
        {
            if (_isValueCached)
                return _cachedValue;

            if (HasValue)
                return ParseAndCacheValue(ValueText, out _cachedValue, out _isValueCached);

            return Default;
        }
        set
        {
            ValueText = value.ToString();
            _cachedValue = value;
            _isValueCached = true;
        }
    }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public bool HasDefault { get { return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(_defaultText); } }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public bool HasValue { get { return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(_valueText); } }

    private T ParseAndCacheValue(string text, out T cache, out bool isCached)
    {
        cache = _parsingFunc(text);
        isCached = true;

        return cache;
    }
}
```

And a sample program to demonstrate usage...

```
public class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        UserSettings userSettings = new UserSettings();
        userSettings.User.Default = "Programmer";
        userSettings.Level.Default = 2;
        userSettings.Level.Value = 99;

        XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(UserSettings));

        string serializedUserSettings;
        using (StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter())
        {
            xmlSerializer.Serialize(stringWriter, userSettings);
            serializedUserSettings = stringWriter.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
        }

        UserSettings deserializedUserSettings;
        using (StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(serializedUserSettings))
        {
            deserializedUserSettings = (UserSettings)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(stringReader);
        }

        Console.Out.WriteLine("User: HasDefault={0}, Default={1}, HasValue={2}, Value={3}", 
            deserializedUserSettings.User.HasDefault ? "Yes" : "No", 
            deserializedUserSettings.User.Default,
            deserializedUserSettings.User.HasValue ? "Yes" : "No", 
            deserializedUserSettings.User.Value);

        Console.Out.WriteLine("Level: HasDefault={0}, Default={1}, HasValue={2}, Value={3}",
            deserializedUserSettings.Level.HasDefault ? "Yes" : "No",
            deserializedUserSettings.Level.Default,
            deserializedUserSettings.Level.HasValue ? "Yes" : "No",
            deserializedUserSettings.Level.Value);

        Console.Out.WriteLine("IsFullscreen: HasDefault={0}, Default={1}, HasValue={2}, Value={3}",
            deserializedUserSettings.IsFullscreen.HasDefault ? "Yes" : "No",
            deserializedUserSettings.IsFullscreen.Default,
            deserializedUserSettings.IsFullscreen.HasValue ? "Yes" : "No",
            deserializedUserSettings.IsFullscreen.Value);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
using System.ComponentModel;

[Serializable]
[XmlRoot("Settings")]
public class UserSettings
{
    [DefaultValue("Yogesh")]
    [XmlElement("User")]
    public string User { get; set; }

    [DefaultValue("1st")]
    [XmlElement("Level")]
    public string Level { get; set; }

}
```

For more info see [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.defaultvalueattribute%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Comment: The 'defalut' value should come from the XML and not hardcoded.

Comment: @Codehelp default value is the value we assign when there's no value exists, if we are getting the value from the xml itself then what's the use of default value ?? & you haven't mentioned that in OP. Please edit your question and be more specific about the solution you want.

Comment: It mentions clearly 'return the default attribute value'. I think you are confused between the DefaultValue decorator and the 'default' attribute tag in my question. The DefaultValue decorator is hardcoding the actual value which will not work in this case. Hope this is clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can use  Default Value attribute for the property.

In you case it will be,

```
[Serializable]
[XmlRoot("Settings")]
public class UserSettings
{
    [XmlElement("User")]
    [DefaultValue("Programmer")]
    public string User { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Level")]
    [DefaultValue(2)]
    public string Level { get; set; }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is a way to tell string to use that default xml attribute.  You will have to deserialize each of those object into a structure that has the default value as a property which is an xml attribute.

Here's an example...

```
[Serializable]
[XmlRoot("Settings")]
public class UserSettings
{
    [XmlElement("User")]
    public DefaultableValue User { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Level")]
    public DefaultableValue Level { get; set; }

}

[Serializable]
public class DefaultableValue
{
    [XmlAttribute("default")]
    public string Default { get; set; }

    [XmlText]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

And sample program to demonstrate usage...

```
public class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        UserSettings userSettings = new UserSettings();
        userSettings.User = new DefaultableValue()
            {
                Default = "Programmer", 
                Value = "Tyler"
            };
        userSettings.Level = new DefaultableValue()
            {
                Default = "2", 
                Value = "99"
            };

        XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(UserSettings));

        string serializedUserSettings;
        using (StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter())
        {
            xmlSerializer.Serialize(stringWriter, userSettings);
            serializedUserSettings = stringWriter.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
        }

        UserSettings deserializedUserSettings;
        using (StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(serializedUserSettings))
        {
            deserializedUserSettings = (UserSettings)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(stringReader);
        }

        Console.Out.WriteLine("User: Default={0}, Actual={1}", 
            deserializedUserSettings.User.Default, 
            deserializedUserSettings.User.Value);

        Console.Out.WriteLine("Level: Default={0}, Actual={1}", 
            deserializedUserSettings.Level.Default, 
            deserializedUserSettings.Level.Value);
    }
}
```

(Note that I have the default values in code, but they very well could have come from the xml file)